# How can I parse a JSON object containing a colon

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I have an object which comes back as part of a return data from a REST server. It is part of an item object.

(I don't have control over the REST server so I can't change the data received):

```
{
    "Option:Color":"Red,Green,Blue,Orange",
    "Option:Size":"Small,Medium,Large"
}
```

What I want to end up with is some control over this, so that I can display the results when a product is selected in my app. It will appear in a modal. I am using Marionette/Backbone/Underscore/JQuery etc. but this is more of a JavaScript question.

I have tried multiple ways of getting at the data with no success. I would like to be able to have the options in a nested array, but I'd be open to other suggestions...

Basically this kind of structure

```
var Color=('Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Orange')
var Size('Small', 'Medium', 'Large')
```

The Object structure is fine, just need to be able to translate it to an array and take out the 'Option' keyword

Important to mention that I have no idea what the different options might be when I receive them - the bit after Options: might be any form of variation, color, size, flavour etc.

Comment: Why don't use `var Color = OptionColor.split(",");` ?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the parsed JSON and create new keys on a new object. That way you don't have to create the var names yourself; it's automatically done for you, albeit as keys in a new object.

```
var obj = {
  "Option:Color":"Red,Green,Blue,Orange",
  "Option:Size":"Small,Medium,Large"
}

function processObj() {
    var newObj = {};
    for (var k in obj) {
        var key = k.split(':')[1].toLowerCase();
        var values = obj[k].split(',');
        newObj[key] = values;
    }
    return newObj;
}

var processedObj = processObj(obj);
for (var k in processedObj) {
  console.log(k, processedObj[k])
  // color ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange"], size ["Small", "Medium", "Large"]
}
```

**Edit**: OP I've updated the code here and in the jsfiddle to show you how to loop over the new object to get the keys/values.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/pmwYL/29/).

Comment: This looks very interesting. So if I were to use something like console.log(newObj["Color"]); I could get at the Color information. But does this get me 'Color' in some way I can use it, *without* knowing what the label will be in advance?

Comment: Yes. Or even `newObj.Color`. That said I always prefer my keys to be all lowercase so I've changed the code slightly to reflect that. Now you get it by `newObj.color`. Have a play around in the _jsfiddle_ to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json  = {
             "Option:Color":"Red,Green,Blue,Orange",
             "Option:Size":"Small,Medium,Large"
            };
var color = json['Option:Color'].split(',');
var size  = json['Option:Size'].split(',');
```

Comment: this will not do it: "the bit after Options: might be any form of variation, color, size, flavour etc.", so he needs a dynamic approach

Answer (score 1):

Try this to do get a solution without hardcoding all the option names into your code:

```
var x = {
  "Option:Color":"Red,Green,Blue,Orange",
  "Option:Size":"Small,Medium,Large"
};

var clean = {};

$.each(x, function(key, val){ //iterate over the options you have in your initial object
    var optname = key.replace('Option:', ''); //remove the option marker
    clean[optname] = val.split(","); //add an array to your object named like your option, splitted by comma
});
```

clean will contain the option arrays you want to create

EDIT: Okay, how you get the names of your object properties like "color", which are now the keys in your new object? Thats the same like before, basically:

```
$.each(clean, function(key, val){
  //key is the name of your option here
  //val is the array of properties for your option here
  console.log(key, val);
});
```

Of course we stick to jQuery again. ;)

Comment: You really don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: No but he wrote that he already included jQuery so why not use it...?

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery for simple things that "pure" JavaScript is perfectly capable of. Imho it's better not to create unnecessary dependencies on external libraries and not to have to rely on jQuery to work properly (not a big issue, though) ... and it's lazy ;-)

Comment: @JoDavid: The question is tagged with "backbone.js" so jQuery will almost certainly be around anyway and Underscore is guaranteed to be around. So using one of those libraries isn't exactly adding extra dependencies. And "pure" JavaScript is perfectly capable of doing everything jQuery does (oddly enough) so your reasoning would lead us to never use jQuery at all. I'd be sorely tempted to use `_.reduce` for this.

Comment: You are generalizing my answer. I regulary use jQuery and love it ... for working with browser specific stuff. But a `for in` loop, seriously? :-) And then there is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question and of course this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177988/how-can-stack-overflow-users-be-encouraged-to-use-jquery-only-when-appropriate/178048#178048

Comment: I like this solution too. JQuery is part of the stack already so it wouldn't add any more overhead I suppose if I chose to go this way. I would ask the same question as above though - how do I get at 'Color' and 'Size' if I don't know their values in advance? I need to display these values in a template so they can be picked. How would I iterate over that to expose the info?

Comment: Good grief. Underscore is so passé. Use Lodash instead :p

Comment: Resource overheads aside, @user2703990, there might be some performance costs from doing something simple in vanilla JS rather than rely on jQuery or underscore.

Comment: @user2703990, I've updated my answer to show you how to loop over the new object to get at the keys/values.